# Is checking whether req.body.csrfToken and req.cookies.csrfToken match is enough to prevent CSRF attack?

Tags: csrf, csrf-token

my goal is to implement CSRF Token. But I am confused on how I should generate the CSRF Token.

CMIIW:

1. I am assuming that malicious website can't get access to the target-domain.com's cookie. The malicious website only can send a request like `target-domain.com/delete-user`, which will also send the target-domain.com's cookie. Note: The malicious website do not know the CSRF Token value.

If my assumption is correct, then it is safe to create an end point which is `/csrfToken` which will return a csrfToken cookie.

And since target-domain.com can call the `getCookie('csrfToken')` function, target-domain.com can send request to `target-domain.com/delete-user` with body csrfToken.